# Python3, Rpy2 and R 3.1.1 ImportError undefined symbol

Tags: r, python-3.4, raspberry-pi3, rpy2

I used pip and installed RPy2 on my raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian Jessie. I have a working installation of R 3.1.1 (tried upgrading to a newer version but couldn't seem to make it work). I get a strange error when I try to run `python3 -m rpy2.tests`. I get the following error:

```
$ python3 -m rpy2.tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rpy2/tests.py", line 23, in 
<module>
    import rpy2.tests_rpy_classic
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rpy2/tests_rpy_classic.py", 
line 3, in <module>
    import rpy2.rpy_classic as rpy
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rpy2/rpy_classic.py", line 5, 
in <module>
    import rpy2.rinterface as ri
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py", 
line 92, in <module>
    from rpy2.rinterface._rinterface import (baseenv,
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-
packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: 
installChar
```

Can anyone point me to what I need to do to fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error:   it ended up being due to the version of R (3.1.0 or 3.2.0).

Updating to R 3.4.0 fixed it.